# Clojure macro inside another macro: how to generate string from symbol

Tags: macros, clojure, quil

Probably the title is not 100% correct, but let me show you the issue:

```
(defmacro nvp!
  [n width height]
  `(q/defsketch (symbol (str (name '~n) "-viewport" ))
                  :title (name '~n))
```

In short: there's a macro called `defsketch` (it's part of the lib `quil`, but that does not matter). It's signature is basically `defsketch [applet-name & options]`, and it creates something and binds it to a var called `applet-name`. For some reason, I want to wrap this into another macro that -- among other things -- takes an `applet-name` parameter, extends that name into `applet-name-viewport` and passes that to `defsketch`. I, however, am unable to figure out how to do that correctly (using macroexpand on the code above (`(pprint (macroexpand(nvp test-name 500 500)))`, I get

```
(def(clojure.core/symbol (clojure.core/str (clojure.core/name 'my-namespace.core/test-name) "-viewport"))
 (quil.applet/applet
 :title (clojure.core/name 'my-namespace.core/test-name)))
```

`(clojure.core/symbol (clojure.core/str (clojure.core/name 'my-namespace.core/test-name) "-viewport")` -- this part looks good, but it should be evaluated somehow before passing it to the inner macro...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unquote the form that generates the new symbol instead of the original symbol itself.

Here is a small example of how to accomplish this using a `defn` like macro for the inner macro:

```
(defmacro mydefn
  [name & body]
  `(defn ~name ~@body))

(defmacro defnview
  [n & body]
  `(mydefn ~(symbol (str (name n) "-viewport")) ~@body))

;; OR

(defmacro defnview
  [n & body]
  (let [n (symbol (str (name n) "-viewport"))]
    `(mydefn ~n ~@body)))
```

Example:

```
(defnview foo [a] a)
;; => #'user/foo-viewport

(foo-viewport 1)
;; => 1

(macroexpand '(defnview foo [a] a))
;; => (def foo-viewport (clojure.core/fn ([a] a)))
```

Comment: Thanks - it's not completely clear yet though. In your examples you are not calling a second macro -- I need do to that, and the argument of the second macro should be a mutated version of the argument of the outer macro.

Comment: @MateVarga it doesn't make a different since you are returning a new form - if that happens to be a macro, it will be expanded. I'll update my answer with an inner macro.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got it now. I'm very new to clj and macros are a bit though after 2 weeks :)